# Method to solve this non-linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I have a differential equation as follows and have got no idea how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

$$ \frac{d^2t}{dx^2} -2 (\frac{dt}{dx} )^2\frac{1}{t} = 0 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t''-2\frac{(t')^2}{t}=0 \iff \frac{t''}{t'}=2\frac{t'}{t}$$
Now you can integrate in both side and get
$$\log|t'|=2\log|t|+\tilde C\iff t' = C\cdot t^2$$
and you can finish from here.